# tool for tracking which php files are called for a particular page

Tags: php, joomla

I am building a website using Joomla 2.5 and wondered if there are any tools available which can track which php files are called for a particular web page rendering.

For example, say I have a calendar component installed.  If I click a menu item taking me to the calendar page of my site several php files are executed to generate the page.

How can I get a listing, or trail, of which particular php files were called?

Comment: Have you tried `debug_backtrace()`?

Comment: use xdebug profiler and xdebug debugger together

Comment: I don't know, but whichever system that relies on _files_ instead of _classes_, _services_, _layers_...is suboptimal. Don't let the physical representation of your program interfere with its abstraction.